# What is local volume fraction of material?

Tags: volume, material-science

I'm reading a text on [shape optimization by homogenization method](http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~jouve/papers/euroef.pdf).

There the author describes that the **composite structure** resulting from the homogenization method is

> determined by two functions: $\theta(x)$, its **local volume fraction of
>   material** taking values between 0 and 1 and ...

What is local volume fraction of material? What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

local volume fractions is similar to the volume fraction but of a particular local boundary in a system.

Comment: Hi @jass, welcome to PSE. This does not constitute an answer. Please expand on it, or delete it.